# How to assign a list of instance methods to a class variable?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

I have this class which works:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.checks = [self.check1, self.check2]

    def check1(self):
        return True

    def check2(self):
        return True

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check()
```

The instance variable `checks` is not specific to instances, so I want to move it to class level, here is my attempt :

```
class Point:

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.checks = [cls.check1, cls.check2]
        return super(Point, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def check1(self):
        return True

    def check2(self):
        return True

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check()
```

The class definition `seems` to work (in the sense that there are no `syntax` errors), but when I run it, got error :

```
TypeError: Point.check1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

*Update*

With @juanpa.arrivillaga's solution, my problem is solved :

```
class ParentFuncs:
    def check1(self):
        print("check1")

    def check2(self):
        print("check2")

    checks = [check1, check2]

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check(self)


class ChildFuncs(ParentFuncs):
    def check3(self):
        print("check3")

    def check4(self):
        print("check4")

    checks = ParentFuncs.checks + [check3, check4]

ChildFuncs().run_all_checks()
# Output
check1
check2
check3
check4
```

Comment: Your list *is* specific to an instance, because it's a list of bound method objects.

Comment: `__new__` is called when creating each instance so you haven't saved anything from your `__init__` solution. `cls.check1` is a function (`self` isn't added automatically) while `self.check1` is a method (`self` is added). You could do `check(self)` to get it it work, but you haven't saved anything with `__new__`.

Comment: Do you want to be able to override check1 and check2 in subclasses? Then `checks` is dependent on the MRO of whatever subclass creates the instance. Your first solution is an easy way to deal with that.

Comment: @tdelaney well, you are saving the instance variable, but you are still doing unecessary extra work when you create the instance. You can do without both!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - true, but I assume OP has some reason why making a list instead of just calling `check1()` and `check2()` in `run_all_checks` (or making the list there) is better. I'm not sure if overwriting a class variable on each instance is a particularly good idea when subclasses overriding checkX could come into play.

Comment: @chepner You are right in absolute, but you see that juanpa.arrivillaga's solution provide some kind of `late binding` which solved partially my problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't need to `override` checkX, but I do have parent-child relationship, for example, child has a few checks which `complement` (not `override`) parent's checks. I know about the work involved by `__new__`. If I have billions of points, I save a few GB of memory by moving `checks` to class level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it in the class body, and then in `run_all_checks`, make sure to pass the instance explicitly, because they will just be functions, not bound methods (which get created *when accessing a method through and instance*):

```
class Point:

    def check1(self):
        return True

    def check2(self):
        return False

    checks = [check1, check2]

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            print(check(self))


point = Point()
point.run_all_checks()
```

Note, this doesn't behave the same way in the case of inheritance. But that is probably OK, depending on your use-case.

You *could* do something like `checks = ['check1', 'check2']` and then in `run_all_checks`, something like `getattr(self, check)()`, but IMO, this is more brittle. So I would go with your original approach in that case if I intended these methods to be overridden in subclasses.

Comment: But it is something of a ticking time-bomb in the code. It would be pretty natural to override `check2` and expect the code to still work.

Comment: @tdelaney sort of, but is it really very different from overriding `__getitem__` in a subclass of `dict` but then finding that `.get()` doesn't use your `__getiitem__` implementation as you might hope? Not all classes are designed around being extensible in this way. Whether that's appropriate is something you can judge on a case-by-case basis

Comment: With a little more work, you can make `Point` inherit from a base class that uses `__init_subclass__` to add `cls.check` et al. to `cls.check`. That way, `Point` (and any subclass of `Point`) has its own `check` attribute populated with inherited and its own overriden methods.

Comment: @chepner I mean, you *could do that* but unless saving memory is a strong requirement, I don't know why you wouldn't just to `self.checks = [self.check1, self.check2, ...]` in `__init__` because the problem is solved more elegantly in that way, IMO